# Ionic 3 invalid css value in variables.scss file

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I'm getting a weird error in my colors variable, my code:

```
$colors: (
  primary:    (base: #488aff, contrast:#000),
  secondary:  (base: #32db64, contrast:#000),
  danger:     (base: #f53d3d, contrast:#000),
  light:      (base: #f4f4f4, contrast:#000),
  dark:       (base: #222, contrast:#000),
  font:        (base: #fe5295, contrast:#000)
);
```

the error I'm getting

```
(primary: (base: #488aff, contrast: #000), secondary: (base: #32db64, contrast: #000), danger: (base: #f53d3d, contrast: #000), light: (base: #f4f4f4, contrast: #000), dark: (base: #222, contrast: #000), font: (base: #fe5295, contrast: #000)) isn't a valid CSS value.
```

My setup:

```
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 6.4.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.4
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v6.9.2
    npm  : 5.5.1
    OS   : Windows 10
```

Any ideas about what might be the issue?

Comment: I've just copied that code as it is in a brand new project, and works properly. When are you getting that error? When running `ionic serve`?

Comment: @sebaferreras I just did the same and yes, it works fine, maybe one of the npm modules is causing this error?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `node_modules` folder an do an `npm install` just in case?

Comment: @sebaferreras It was actually one of node_modules, I reinstalled couple of times, but didn't work. I tried removing one by one and I figured out which one was causing the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the error was coming from `variables.scss` file, actually it was appearing because a npm library called `ion2-calendar`, once I removed it from my code everything went back to normal!

Comment: Glad to hear that you found the issue! :)